# Htaccess to force use WWW for mutlidomain

Tags: .htaccess, forcing

I found this code to force using www.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

But i have many domain that pointed to same directory. So i need a version of this code for multiple domains. It must run on any domain, is it possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
```

It will redirect all request without a subdomain to www.domainame.tld.

Comment: Just wanted to say cheers for this. It's dynamic and works perfectly.